# OpenShift: ballerina: cannot find program file 'hello_docker.balx'"

Tags: ballerina

I've a docker image on OpenShift that fails to be deployed with the log message bellow:

**"ballerina: cannot find program file 'hello_docker.balx'"**

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;
import ballerinax/docker;

@docker:Expose {}
listener http:Listener helloWorldEP = new(9090);

@docker:Config {
    name: "helloworld",
    tag: "v1.0"
}
@http:ServiceConfig {
    basePath: "/helloWorld"
}
service helloWorld on helloWorldEP {
    resource function sayHello(http:Caller outboundEP, http:Request request) {
        http:Response response = new;
        response.setTextPayload("Hello World from Docker ! \n");
        var responseResult = outboundEP->respond(response);
        if (responseResult is error) {
            error err = responseResult;
            log:printError("Error sending response", err = err);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you building the docker image using OpenShift's build configs ?

Comment: No, I'm just building it using `ballerina build helloworld.bal` followed by ...

`docker tag helloworld:v1.0 [our-registry]/tools/helloworld:v1.0` ... 
`docker push [our-registry]/tools/helloworld:v1.0` ... 
`oc.exe import-image [my-openshift-namespace]/helloworld:v1.0 --from='[our-registry]/tools/helloworld:v1.0' --scheduled=true --confirm=true`

Comment: I tried the above locally. It works as expected. Did you try running the docker image locally after running `ballerina build helloworld.bal` ?

Comment: Yes, I can run it locally. The Dockerfile reads "COPY helloWorld.balx /home/ballerina", but the image in OpenShift trying to run the command "/bin/sh -c ballerina run helloWorld.balx" doesn't have the .balx file in the /home/ballerina folder.

Comment: Yes, that is because the working directory is set to `/home/ballerina` in the base image(https://github.com/ballerinax/docker/blob/v0.990.2/base/docker/Dockerfile#L41). By any chance has the working directory changed ? Can you try executing a `pwd` inside the container so we know the location in which the command is executed from ?

Comment: We found the problem. I don't have the information why but I understand it as a volume was mounted and hided the /home folder.

Comment: I think the volume mount at `/home` may have removed `hello_docker.balx'` file since its located at `/home/ballerina`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem. I don't have the information why but I understand it as a volume was mounted and hided the /home folder.